# What does this exception from Blaze Advisor mean

Tags: c#

When trying to invoke a Blaze rule from C# with this line of code:

```
return (T)invokeService(serviceName, entrypointId, null, applicationArgs);
```

We get the following exception:

> Type 'com.blazesoft.server.local.NdLocalServerException' in assembly
>   'com.blazesoft.AdvisorSvr, Version=6.10.143.12, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=4d5643bfb1cd71f0' is not marked as serializable..

If we test the rule inside Blaze with the same input data it works fine.

Anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Does the exception happen on that line or after the method returns?

Comment: what is invokeService(); doing?

Comment: @JustinNiessner, on that line.

Comment: @CalebKeith, this is a method on the Blaze dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `invokeService` is throwing a `NdLocalServerException` across AppDomains. Since the Exception isn't serializable (which, according to Microsoft, they all should be), you're getting another Exception that the original Exception type wasn't serializable.